# Java : File get delete with Files.delete(path), when I try create same file name in next line it will create the old one(content will delete )

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have this code

```
Files.delete(Paths.get("a.txt"));
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("a.txt");
```

First line will delete file,
second line will create file but when i checked file created date it will give old one.

Comment: what do you mean by giving old one? you just enter the same name, no wonder it give you the just `old` one. also you notice the content in it was purged, since this file had been deleted once.

Comment: @user3164355 - "refresh" before checking file created date

Comment: @Rugal old one means I am creating file after delete that file but when i am checking file created date it will give old one. And yes content was purged but i wanted to work on created date so i want latest one.

Comment: @user3164355 isnt the date of creation newest one?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP yes i have checked but its giving the old one.

Comment: What exactly does `Paths.get("a.txt")` return?

Comment: Exactly Path to `a.txt`  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not because you declare a new instance of `FileWriter` that the underlying file is affected or even created in any ways.

According to the Javadoc, the constructor will throw an IOException in these cases (java 7)

`IOException - if the named file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason`

Try writing something in your file.

Also, you should be consistent and use `Paths.get` either in both statements or not at all. AFAIK `Paths.get` is filesystem dependent (in other words you may not be deleting the file that you are trying to recreate).

Comment: I have write in file also but the same problem, new content get write in file but the modified date is latest one but created date is old one.Files.delete() has Files.delete(Path) constructor & this is not Path argument constructor is not available for FileWriter.

Comment: What OS is this ? What about `new File("a.txt").delete()`

Comment: Windows 7 & I have tried on Linux but the same problem.With new File() also the same problem.